# folder structure of .net core web application between vs2017 and vs2015

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

When I create a .net core web application with vs2015, there is a **'src'** folder under root folder and all the project folders are all in it.

But when I did it with vs2017, the folder structure is traditionally，which means all the project folders are under the root folder directly.

So is there any reason for this difference? Is it a bug of vs2017 or by design? I really like the behavior of vs2015 but I wanna using vs2017.

By the way, both professional versiton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some searching, this is caused by the project file. vs2017 abandoned project.json and xproj file of the .net core project, and migrates them to .csproj file.

for your reference：
[VS 2017 release note](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes)

> - MSBuild support for .NET Core projects, with a simplified csproj project format that makes it easier to edit by hand, without the need to unload the project.
> - Editing .NET Core .csproj file is as simple as a right click on project in Solution Explorer and choosing “Edit”.
> - Support for file wildcards in project file, where you don’t have to enumerate all the source code file names, which keeps the csproj file compact in size.
>     NuGet package references are now part of the csproj file, consolidating all project references in one file.
> - Interop between .NET Core, .NET Standard and .NET Framework projects. For example, a .NET Core project can add a project-to-project reference to a .NET Standard project.
> - Cross-target multiple target frameworks in one project.
>     Existing project.json .NET Core projects will automatically migrate to csproj when opened in Visual Studio, or you can manually migrate them using the .NET Command Line Interface (CLI).
> - Easily configure continuous build integration for your ASP.NET Core application with Docker support and continuous build delivery to your Azure Container Services from within the Visual Studio IDE.